# How do I write a core location with MVVM architecture and perform unit testing?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, unit-testing, core-location

I want to develop an app to get device location and search near by areas. I have a basic understanding of MVVM architecture but so far I could not find a way to separate core location logic into view models . I also want to write sample unit test cases for the same.

Comment: If you are calling your custom API for near-by places then you can test it passing one location coordinates for your Remote API call.
If you are using Google SDK for APIs then you don't have to write unit test as usually Google SDK does it internally.
Your location manager should handle (user permission and getting the user current location) and your view model just have to use the manager so you can write separate Unit test for your view model and location manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `LocationService` protocol that defines all methods (for instance `fetchCurrentPosition`).
Then create a concrete class conforming to that protocol, that implements apple  `CoreLocation` services; this class will be used by the view model for example, and it will be injected in the initializer. Think something like:

```
class MyViewModel {

    let locationService: LocationService

    init(locationService: LocationService = LocationServiceImpl()) {
        self.locationService = locationService
    }

}
```

`LocationServiceImpl` is the class conforming to `LocationService` that actually uses apple `CoreLocation`; in this way, you can later mock every function of your location service by creating for example `LocationServiceMock` class that conforms to `LocationService`; in your unit tests, you'll create a view model with the mocked service.